# If fluids exert force in all directions then why do objects float?

Tags: forces, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, buoyancy

My question is that when we place a body in water it exerts a buoyant force but it exerts an equal force in downward direction then why its buoyant force is greater and the object floats?

Comment: The same in all directions does not mean the same in every location.

Comment: Take a look at the diagram in this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/597482/93729 (shamelessly self promoting)

Comment: I guess it is the time of year when they start teaching the Fluids section in physics 101...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy

Answer (score 17):

The force is equal in all directions, but it also depends on the depth. An object of finite size, submerged in a liquid,  has its bottom and upper parts at different depths, and the force at the bottom is bigger than that at the top. An object floating on the surface even doesn't have its upper part in the liquid.

Comment: Even more simply, when it is on the surface there is no fluid on the top of the object, so all the vertical force is upward if the object is a box.

Comment: @RossMillikan what is the difference in between air pressure and water pressure at the surface of a lake? Right where the air and water touch.